# How to move a sprite across the screen ? cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I have a question, I want to make an animation which is moving my CCSprite across the screen (Repeateforever) but what is the most important for me is that when my object is accrossing the screen (for example a ball) and its is starting to disappear i want to see that part in the opposite part of the screen is it possible ?

kuba.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Actor.png"];
[self addChild:sprite];

CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
sprite.position = ccp(0, size.height/2.0f);

id move      = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0f position:ccp(size.width, size.height/2.0f)];
id moveBack  = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:2.0f position:ccp(0, size.height/2.0f)];
id sequence  = [CCSequence actions:move, moveBack, nil];
id repeate   = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];

[sprite runAction:repeate];
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean Asteroids-style: object leaving area on one side of the screen and enters screen on the exact opposite side. Possibly displayed partially on both (or all four) screen borders.

Yes, that's possible, but not without using 2 or 4 sprites. If your sprite can leave the screen only to the left/right or up/down 2 sprites suffices. If you want a complete wrap-around-at-screen-borders type of world, you need to have 4 sprites.

The general idea is to use the sprite's contentSize and the screen size to test if the sprite has (partially) left the screen. Then display the other sprites at a position plus or minus the width and/or height of the screen so that they appear as if the sprite wraps seamlessly from one border to another.

You need 4 sprites for the corners. Imagine the sprite's center point is exactly at 0,0 which means the upper right quarter of the sprite is drawn in the lower left corner. If the world wraps at the screen border, you're supposed to see the other quarters of the sprite at the upper left, upper right and lower right corners as well.

And no, there's no trick where you can do this with only a single sprite. You need 2 or 4 and synchronize their positions with the "master" sprite.

I once implemented this. I'll post the code that updates the "sprite doubles" properties as is, no guarantees and it's not a copy-paste solution. It does show the general idea of how to synchronize the sprites. The doubles are stored in an array and there are four of them:

```
-(void) updateSpriteDoublesProperties
{
    CCSprite* sprite = (CCSprite*)self.owner.node;

    for (int i = 0; i < kNumOpposingSprites; i++)
    {
        CCSprite* spriteDouble = spriteDoubles_->arr[i];
        spriteDouble.rotation = sprite.rotation;
        spriteDouble.scale = sprite.scale;
        spriteDouble.flipX = sprite.flipX;
        spriteDouble.flipY = sprite.flipY;

        CGPoint pos = self.owner.node.position;
        CGPoint oppositePosition = pos;

        if (i == 0 || i == 1)
        {
            if (pos.x > boundaryCenter_.x)
            {
                oppositePosition.x = pos.x - (boundary_.size.width - boundary_.origin.x);
            }
            else
            {
                oppositePosition.x = pos.x + (boundary_.size.width - boundary_.origin.x);
            }
        }
        if (i == 0 || i == 2)
        {
            if (pos.y > boundaryCenter_.y)
            {
                oppositePosition.y = pos.y - (boundary_.size.height - boundary_.origin.y);
            }
            else
            {
                oppositePosition.y = pos.y + (boundary_.size.height - boundary_.origin.y);
            }
        }

        spriteDouble.position = oppositePosition;
    }
}
```